# Using helpers in model: how do I include helper dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I'm writing a model that handles user input from a text area.  Following the advice from [http://blog.caboo.se/articles/2008/8/25/sanitize-your-users-html-input](http://web.archive.org/web/20090416200046/http://blog.caboo.se/articles/2008/8/25/sanitize-your-users-html-input), I'm cleaning up the input in the model before saving to database, using the before_validate callback.

The relevant parts of my model look like this:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base {
  before_validation :clean_input

  ...

  protected

  def clean_input
    self.input = sanitize(self.input, :tags => %w(b i u))
  end
end
```

Needless to say, this doesn't work.  I get the following error when I try and save a new Post.

```
undefined method `white_list_sanitizer' for #<Class:0xdeadbeef>
```

Apparently, SanitizeHelper creates an instance of HTML::WhiteListSanitizer, but when I mix it into my model it can't find HTML::WhiteListSanitizer.  Why?  What can I do about this to fix it?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Just change the first line as follows :

```
include ActionView::Helpers
```

that will make it works.

**UPDATE:** For Rails 3 use:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(str)
```

Credit goes to [lornc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7593347/59168)

Comment: couldn't have said it better myself

Comment: Thanks.

I got it to work by moving the include to inside of the class definition.

Comment: With this I get `stack level too deep`. It is in a before_save method.

Comment: @Cort3z it means there is infinite loop, check on your field name and function name

Comment: Please don't mix view layer concerns with active record models. That's a terrible practice. A much better approach is to put a standalone input data sanitizer object in front of AR and retrieve "clean" attributes from it.

Comment: I had to use `ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(str, tags: [])`

Comment: This is a very bad solution and should be avoided like fire. Rails is based on MVC(Model View Controller) framework where helper comes in View part so you should not mix view helper methods with model.

Comment: Note that `ActionController::Base.helpers` only gets you the built in Rails helpers. If you also want your custom application-wide helpers, you need `ApplicationController.helpers`.

Answer (score 143):

This gives you just the helper method without the side effects of loading every ActionView::Helpers method into your model:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(str)
```

Comment: For the slow people like me - you don't need to include anything, just use ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize("On the string you want to sanitize")

Comment: Thank you, worked in Rails 2.3.14 while the accepted answer did not.

Comment: I added a method to the application_helper, but I wasn't able to access it from the model using ActionController::Base.helpers.my_method(options) using Rails 3.0.3?

Answer (score 43):

This works better for me:

**Simple:**

```
ApplicationController.helpers.my_helper_method
```

**Advance:**

```
class HelperProxy < ActionView::Base
  include ApplicationController.master_helper_module

  def current_user
    #let helpers act like we're a guest
    nil
  end       

  def self.instance
    @instance ||= new
  end
end
```

Source: http://makandracards.com/makandra/1307-how-to-use-helper-methods-inside-a-model

Comment: The `ApplicationController.master_helper_module` does not exist any more in Rails 3 and 4 it appears. The `ApplicationController.helpers` is a nice one though.

Comment: I voted for this (the simple option) because it suited my needs - I only need one helper that is using information saved by a before filter in ApplicationController, so in my case making the association explicit is a reminder that there is a coupling. [Use case is multi domain app, that issues emails via a model notifier with a url link back to the app - this url changes depending on the domain of web request]

Answer (score 26):

To access helpers from your own controllers, just use:

```
OrdersController.helpers.order_number(@order)
```

Comment: Just using `ApplicationController.helpers.order_number(@order)`. That mean the `order_number` was locate on `Order Helper`

Comment: @rowanu He's saying "to access (helpers from your own controllers)", not "(to access helpers) from your own controllers".

Answer (score 20):

If you want to use a the `my_helper_method` inside a model, you can write:

```
ApplicationController.helpers.my_helper_method
```

Answer (score 14):

I wouldn't recommend any of these methods. Instead, put it within its own namespace.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def clean_input
    self.input = Helpers.sanitize(self.input, :tags => %w(b i u))
  end

  module Helpers
    extend ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 7:

```
full_sanitizer = Rails::Html::FullSanitizer.new
full_sanitizer.sanitize("<a href="javascript:alert('hacked!')">Some dangerous input</a>")
```

List of available sanitizers: https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer#sanitizers

Your model would then be:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base {
  before_validation :clean_input

  ...

  protected

  def clean_input
    full_sanitizer = Rails::Html::FullSanitizer.new
    self.input = full_sanitizer.sanitize(self.input, :tags => %w(b i u))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Many suggests `include` or `extend` the entire helper library within the class, which is overkill.

I recommend just delegating the helper methods you need.

For example

```rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :sanitize, to: 'ActionController::Base.helpers'
end
```

This will give you access to `sanitize` within the model.