# How to sanitize data (remove html tags) before saving a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was wondering if Rails3 had an easy way to remove html tags from the input data before saving it in the database.

Right now the data is sanitized on the view level by HAML. JS doesn't get executed and stuff, but I'd like to completely remove potentially harmful data.

Basically, my question is: is there a helper I could use in a before_save filter to safely strip the tags out?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm using [sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/) for this jobs which is based on nokogiri. Is simpler to use, because you don't have to access view helpers in your model.

Comment: Why do you suggest to add an additional gem for things which already done inside rails?

Answer (score 5):

I believe what you are looking for is the [sanitize helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess it is what I need. But how do I use it the model?

Comment: Check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489641/using-helpers-in-model-how-do-i-include-helper-dependencies), you can include it in your model `include ActionView::Helpers`