# remove all html tag before validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, html-sanitizing

is there a clean way to remove all html tag of all attributes before validation
I found acts_as_sanitized that seemed to be perfect, but for rails 2 :-s

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sanitize data (remove html tags) before saving a record?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954258/how-to-sanitize-data-remove-html-tags-before-saving-a-record)

Answer (score 0):

The sanitize gem:

https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize

Does what you need.

Call Sanitize.clean(htmlstring). You can whitelist allowed tags as well.