# Strip out script tags before saving to database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For all my models application wide: If the user submits a text_field or text_area containing `<script></script>` tags, then I want rails to strip those tags before saving the user's data entry into the database.

I have already looked at the following posts which are all around 5 years old:

- [post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954258/how-to-sanitize-data-remove-html-tags-before-saving-a-record)
- [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650609/remove-all-html-tag-before-validation)
- [post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576394/remove-all-html-tags-from-attributes-in-rails)

I have also looked at the following docs, but I haven't figured out how to apply them to this situation (removing script tag prior to persisting to database):

- [ActionView Sanitize Helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html)
- [rails-html-sanitizer](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer)

**Example:**

I `scaffold` for a `user` resource:

```
rails g scaffold user first_name last_name age:integer bio:text
```

The user then inputs the following and submits it:

[image: user_input]

The following should be saved to the database for each attribute of this `user` record:

- first_name: Foo
- last_name: Foo
- age: 5
- bio: Bazz

Thanks!

Comment: @Ven it is just a safety net.  In case the programmer does not properly escape within the view, perhaps via an AJAX request.  See this question for an example of when the programmer does not escape properly in the view and the script tags persist in the database: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39039731/sanitize-ajax-response-that-updates-options-in-select-box  we no longer need to worry about that if all script tags are removed prior to saving.

Comment: Rails escapes for you. The programmer doesn't escape himself. This is 2016.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to sanitize when rendering in the HTML, RoR already comes with a helper (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html) that lets you clean those tags automatically.

If you want them clean those bio fields before storing them in your database, there is a gem ([sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize)) which will make it easy. That gem lets you configure which tags you want to preserve (if any) and blacklists the rest.

--
with strong_params you usually have a helper method in your controller in order to **require** and **permit** attributes. After being permitted, you could traverse over those params and check some (or all of them)

```
# using the sanitize gem
def sanitize input_field
  Sanitize.fragment(input_field, Sanitize::Config::RELAXED)
end

def sanitize_product_input 
  # product_params = strong_params filter
  [:first_name, :last_name, :bio].each do |field|
    product_params[field] = sanitize(product_params[field])
  end
  product_params
end
```

or you could do this a bit more generic and create in your application_controller a new method to sanitize inputs

```
# using the sanitize gem
def sanitize input_field
  Sanitize.fragment(input_field, Sanitize::Config::RELAXED)
end

def sanitize_input input_params, fields
  fields.each do |field|
    input_params[field] = sanitize(input_params[field])
  end
end
```

and use that in the methods were you are defining your strong_params filters

```
def product_params 
  fields = [:first_name, :last_name, :bio]
  input_params = params.require(:product).require(fields)
  sanitize_input(input_params, fields)
  input_params
end
```

Comment: can you provide code that applies the `sanitize` gem to solve the provided example in the question? I want to sanitize `first_name`, `last_name`, and `bio` attributes for this model.  But more globally: I also want to sanitize ALL text fields for all forms so that the user can never submit `<script>` tags.  How would I use the sanitize gem with strong_params?

Comment: with strong_params you usually have a helper method in your controller in order to **require** and **permit** attributes. After being permitted, you could traverse over those params and check some (or all of them)

`
def sanitize_product_input 
  # product_params = strong_params filter
  [:first_name, :last_name, :bio].each do |field|
    product_params[field] = sanitize(product_params[field])
  end
  product_params
end
`

Comment: your method `sanitize(product_params[field])` will not work in the controller. The `sanitize` method is a view helper that cannot be used in the controller.

Comment: That is the name of a rails helper for the view. But if you create a new method (sanitize) in your application_controller, then it will work (in the example I use the sanitize gem)

Comment: Thank you for your help.  With the Sanitize gem don't you have to do: `Sanitize.fragment(some_string)`, or even `Sanitize.fragment(some_string, Sanitize::Config::RELAXED)`

Comment: Yes. I updated the code in the previous answer.

Comment: Thanks Hans!  Please accept my minor edit and I will gladly mark your answer as the accepted answer for this question!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use the [sanitize_model_attributes gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/sanitize_model_attributes)

Basically: this overwrites the setters for all the model attributes you specify within the `sanitize_attributes` method so that it can sanitize each attribute's `value`:

**Implementation**:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include SanitizeModelAttributes
  sanitize_attributes :first_name, :last_name, :bio
end
```

And just like that: *all* html tags (not just the script tag) is stripped out prior to saving to the database for the attributes of `first_name`, `last_name`, and `bio`.