# Removing html tags from a form field after the user clicks submit (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm using [wysihtml5](http://xing.github.com/wysihtml5/) in the form of my `Post` model:

**posts/_form.html.erb:**

```
<%= f.text_area :content, id: "wysihtml5-textarea",
                          placeHolder: "Content" %>
```

And displaying the results as `raw` + `sanitize`:

**show.html.erb:**

```
<%= sanitize raw(@post.content), :tags => %w(b i u p br) %>
```

(I'm only allowing `b, i, u, p, and br` tags).

The problem with this is that html tags other than those mentioned above (b, i, u, p, and br), are still getting saved in the text area (they are still visible for the user if he clicks edit). I would like to remove then right after the user clicks submit (like how WordPress' text editor does it).

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Something I'm trying:

**post.rb:**

```
  before_save :remove_html_tags

  def remove_html_tags
    self.content.sanitized_allowed_tags.delete 'div'
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the API docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

Scroll down a bit, maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.after_initialize do
    ActionView::Base.sanitized_allowed_tags.delete 'div'
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:** If you want to strip tags right before the resource is saved, you could do this on the model level with a `before_save` callback. Or in your controller, in the `#create` action right before the resource is saved. If you want to strip certain tags then you could use `#strip_tags`, for example:

```
before_save do |post|
  post.content = strip_tags(post.content)
end
```

but since this is a method from ActiveSupport, you have to include the module in your model:

```
`ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I don't have to specify the `ID` of the form? It works for all the forms on the site?

Comment: Yes it should be global, for everytime you use `#sanitize`.

Comment: But I'm using `sanitize` in the `post` view. So Rails is smart enough to apply it in the `post`'s from once the user submits it? (Sorry, by the way, in which file I'm supposed to place that method)?

Comment: Sorry, misred your question. Updated my answer.

Comment: Something like in my **EDIT**? Please let me know if it is right or if there a better way of writing it.

Comment: Thanks! So I don't need the `config.after_initialize` method anymore? (by the way, how will that code look like if the `before_save` method were in the model?)

Comment: Followed this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489641/using-helpers-in-model-how-do-i-include-helper-dependencies