# How do I call a number_helper in my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, best-in-place

I am using best_in_place gem, and to cut a long story short I can't call this particular helper in my view, because I have to call a custom method in my model to customize how I want the output to look.

This is the call in my view:

```
<td><%= best_in_place firm, :size, :type => :input, :nil => "Click to add Firm Size", :display_as => :in_millions %></td>
```

This is the method in my `Firm` model:

```
def in_millions
    "$#{self.size}M"
end
```

The numbers entered by the user won't be `100000000`, but rather `100`. So I want to take that `100` and have it just read `$100M`. That's what my helper does.

But, for those numbers that are like `12345`, I want the output to look like this: `$12,345M`.

The easiest way I can think is just to add `number_with_delimiter(self.size)` and keep the `$` and `M`, but I can't access that helper method from my model.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include helpers in your model by including [`ActionView::Helpers`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489641/using-helpers-in-model-how-do-i-include-helper-dependencies):

```
# in model
include ActionView::Helpers
```

I wonder, though, if it wouldn't make better sense to keep the presentation on the presentation side. You could just wrap up the extra logic in an alternative helper instead:

```
# in helper
def firm_size_in_millions(firm)
  size = number_with_delimiter(firm.size)
  "$#{size}M"
end

<!-- in view -->
<%= firm_size_in_millions(@firm) %>
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Thanks dude. Although I didn't use EVERYTHING you suggested, you gave me a great foundation upon which I can execute this. Thanks much!!!

Comment: You bet! Glad to hear it helped out :^)

Answer (score 1):

The helpers are considered "presentation" tools -- a currency value or decimal value, for example may be represented differently in some locales or countries than in others.

But if you know all of this, then just `include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` in your model :-)

Comment: Thanks...I used the bulk of his, and just used your `include` because it is more specific and I assume includes less cruft :)