# How to Use Helpermethod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I created an helper in my **application_helper**:

```
 def birthday(geburt)
   f = Date.today
   a = f.year - geburt.year
   a = a - 1 if (
     geburt.month >  f.month or 
    (geburt.month >= f.month and geburt.day > f.day)
    )
    a
 end
```

Now i try tu use this helper in an **model:**

```
 patients = patients.where("birthday(geburtsdatum) >= ?", minimum) if minimum.present?
```

But how you can see in the error i somehow dont use my helper right. "geburtsdatum" is an colomn in my patients model. Thanks **Error:**

```
 SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: birthday: SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients"  WHERE (birthday(geburtsdatum) >= 15) ORDER BY vorname
```

My new code:

```
def find_patients
 patients = Patient.order(:vorname)
 patients = patients.where("nachname like ?", "%#{keyword}%") if keyword.present?
 patients = patients.where("#{geburtsdatum.get_birthday} >= ?", minimum) if   minimum.present?
 patients
end
```

My new error:

```
undefined local variable or method `geburtsdatum' for #<Search:0x4ee51b8>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, then the method is for Date objects.

Including helper is doable as you mentioned in that reference but not a good practice. You can do it for a quick fix, nothing wrong.

Just for your reference, in my opinion a better approach is to extend Date class in your app to add such method and then you can call it on a Date object like `some_date.process_birthday`.

You can add such file in `/app`, or `/initializers`, or `/lib`(better but need manual require).

Then

```
class Date
  def get_birthday
    f = Date.today
    a = f.year - self.year
    if (self.month >  f.month) || (self.month >= f.month && self.day > f.day)
      a = a - 1
    end 
    a
  end
end
```

Comment: Geburtsdatum is german, in englisch = Birthday! But can you explain me your recommendation further? Thanks

Comment: I dont know but here it says http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489641/using-helpers-in-model-how-do-i-include-helper-dependencies

Comment: thanks, i put your  code into initializers get_birthday.rb. Then in the model  patients.where("geburtsdatum.get_birthday >= ?", m..... But somehow it says no such column: geburtsdatum.get_birthday !!!! How do i have to write it? Thanks

Comment: Firstly is the geburtsdatum really exist as a date object? If it is, you need interpolation the ruby code if they are in a string "#{geb.get_birthday} >= ..."

Comment: Yes its defined as date! I have to say we are nearly the goal! I updated the question! There you can see my new code and error!

Comment: If it's undefined, you need to define it. Verify if that variable or method does exist.

Comment: In my patients model i have geburtsdatum:date

Comment: I think the problem is that rails does not know that geburtsdatum belongs to an patient

Comment: If this is a method, it should be class method `def self.geb`

Comment: sorry but where should i put the self?