# CKEditor Raw Text Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, ckeditor

I have the following gem `(CKEditor)` for Rails. It's all working fine however the issue I have is that I'm trying to perform a word count with Rails and because CKeditor is saving a strange string this is not working.

Do you know if there is a way to use the raw command when a snippet is created so that the HTML isn't saved but the raw text is saved instead?

Let me know if you want me to paste any code but you can see what the content is being saved as below.

```
[6] pry(main)> s.content
=> "<p>YACHT!</p>\r\n"
[7] pry(main)>
```

or update my regex to not include the HTML.

Count shown below:

```
 def size_limit 
    book_limit = self.book.size.to_i
    word_count = self.content.scan(/\w+/).size.to_i
    current_snippets_size = (self.book.get_word_count || 0) + word_count 
    errors.add(:base, "Content size is too big") unless word_count < BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]['per'] && current_snippets_size < BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]['total']    
  end
```

I tried using the sanitize gem but it didn't seem to work. I've also tried doing it like Nithin suggested below in the model.

```
word_count = self.content.gsub(/<.*?>/, "").scan(/\w+/).size.to_i
```

However that doesn't seem to work either. I'm a little lost here and have moved onto the other parts of the app until I can figure this out although this part is very crucial as it defines the total number of words per book or snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `s.content.gsub(/<.*?>/, "")`

or

You can use [Sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/)

to use in model see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489641/using-helpers-in-model-how-do-i-include-helper-dependencies)

Comment: Would I be able to use that in the model for the word_count. ie: Sanitize.clean(word_count)

Comment: nope doesn't work in the model, I wonder how I could get that to work just for that object....

Comment: @ShaunFrostDukeJackson see my edit, google up _how to use sanitize in models_ see the first 4 links

Comment: It is still not working, I tried using that but I get unidentfied constant. I only need to clean the HTML out of the count. I want the HTML to stay valid for the outputted text, tried a myriad of ways but nothing has worked so far.