# How to use asset_url helper in Rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, sprockets

How do you get access to the `asset_url` or `asset_path` Sprockets URL helpers inside a Rake task?

---

I have a Rake task that seeds the database with some models. One of the models has the URL to an asset in the Rails app. How do I create a URL for this asset while inside the Rake task?

```
SomeModel.create(image: asset_url('awesome.png'))
```

For now I have a *really* poor solution to the issue.

```
path = URI.join(Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.root_url, '/assets/images/awesome.png')
SomeModel.create(image: path.to_s)
```

Comment: `asset_url` and `asset_path` this helper available only in sass or scss.

Comment: Why are you using a non-relative path? Why do you need to seed the database with these images?

Comment: I assume you are trying to get at why I need to do this in this particular case and help me find a better/easier solution. Thank you, although I really have more than 1 need for the asset_url/asset_path helpers in a Rake task. Do you, @jaysqrd, know a way to enable this?

Comment: I'm wondering if it's worth the time to build something easier. It's possible to access to the `asset_path` via this [module](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/88ee47d052790eefb28732a196b8243700ee9081/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb#L120). You might need to initialize your application to do so (not sure if `rake` will do that by default). The easier thing might be to provide a default the image on your model or just hard code the path in your seeds. Reusing logic like this just isn't worth the work, if its unlikely to change.

Answer (score 1):

**I've just tested out on rails 5.0.2**

Add this into your rake class or controller class

`include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper`

**This will let you use all these methods**
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html

Comment: Including this line in a rake task lead to an error when I attempted to deploy with capistrano: `Sprockets::NotImplementedError: Custom asset_path helper is not implemented`

Answer (score 0):

You have to include `ActionView::Helpers` module Then the asset_path and its other helpers will be available.

```
 include ActionView::Helpers
```

See [Using helpers in model: how do I include helper dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489641/using-helpers-in-model-how-do-i-include-helper-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

In your rake task:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper
```